# Requery & creating database from sql dump: how to?

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, kotlin

I'm trying to use requery https://github.com/requery/requery library with Kotlin and SQLite backend. I have a sql dump, which I want to write to sqlite database in the first launch of an application, and then I want to map data classes to database entities with requery.
Here is data source initialization with table creation:

```
if (!(DataStorage.isDbInitialized(context))) {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val inputStream = context?.resources?.openRawResource(R.raw.dump)
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        var line : String?
        var end = false
        while (!end) {
            line = reader.readLine()
            if(line == null) {
                end = true
            } else {
                builder.append(line)
            }
        }
        db.execSQL(builder.toString())
        onCreate(db)
        DataStorage.setDbInitialized(context)
    }
```

I have to derive this class from both SqlitexDatabaseSource and CommonDataSource to use with Kotlin. SQL query execuled successfully, but when I trying to select all objects from database, this request returns zero sized list:

```
val result : Result<Feat> = (application as MainApp).dataStore.select(Feat::class).get()
    result.each {
        Log.d("TAG", it.name)
    }
```

DTO created as described in documentation:

https://github.com/Syjgin/PathfinderFeats/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/syjgin/pathfinderfeats/model/Feat.kt

Is it possible to initialize requery data with sql dump, or I have to create DTO for each row and submit it via insert method?

Comment: is `db.execSQL` the standard SQLite `execSQL`? If so it will only execute 1 SQL statement but may still work e.g. `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE x (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY); CREATE TABLE xx (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY");` will only create table **x**, the creation of table **xx** does not happen, nor is any error generated/reported. As per *Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.* [execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thank you: for some reasons in kotlin string split by regexp was not working, but, when I change dump to one statement per line and perform execSql for each line, all works perfectly